# Finding name and codes of all airports

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data to get the text I need. I want to find the line that says aberdeen and all lines after it which contain the airport info. Here is a pic of the html hierarchy:

[image]

I am trying to locate the text elements inside the class "i1" with this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.airportcodes.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"i1"})
print(table.text)
```

But I am not getting the values I expect at all. [Here](http://www.airportcodes.org/) is a link to the data if curious. I am new to scraping obviously.

Comment: What values are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your BeautifulSoup parser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.airportcodes.org/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"i1"})
print(table.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the text elements, you can use:

```
soup.get_text()
```

Note: this will give you *all* the text elements.

Answer (score 0):

why are people suggesting selenium? this doesnt dynamically load the data ... requests + re is all you need, you dont even need beautiful soup

```
 data = requests.get('http://www.airportcodes.org/').content
 cities_and_codes =re.findall("([A-Za-z, ]+)\(([A-Z]{3})\)",data)
```

just look for any alphanumeric characters (including also comma and space)
followed by exactly 3 uppercase letters in parenthesis

Comment: interesting regex solution, I appreciate it